# How to register a custom module in OTRS 2.4

Tags: otrs

I have written a custom module for OTRS which is more or less a copy of an existing module (AgentTicketSearch). I placed it in `Kernel\Modules\` like it was said in the developer manual.

When i try to use it, i get the following Errormessage:

> "Module
>   Kernel::Modules::AgentTicketMyModule
>   not registered in Kernel/Config.pm!"

Question: How do i register custom modules in the config.pm?

Answer (score 0):

are you talking about an event handler or what type of module? you will need to add configuration items to the sysconfig for event handlers.

see also : http://forums.otterhub.org/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=10911